# How so I set the 'this' value for a function inside of another function without the using bind()?

Tags: javascript, this

**Objective:** My goal is to call the `setUserName` method of the `clientData` object in such a way that the property: `fullName` is set to the proper values.

**What I've Done:** I attempted the following code:

```
getUserInput.call(clientData,"My","Name",clientData.setUserName)
```

I thought that by doing this, the `this` value inside of the `getUserInput()` function would be set to my object `clientData` which it did.  Furthermore, I thought that all code inside of `getUserInput(){}` would have access to this modified `this` value.  So along that thought process, I figured that the `this` value accessed by `callback()` would also be `clientData`.  Unfortunately, the code inside `callback()` was still accessing a `this` value of `window`.  I do not understand why.

My workaround was to bind `setUserName` to `clientData`.  Is there another way to achieve my goal without modifying `clientData` or `getUserInput()`?

```
var clientData = {
    fullName: "Not Set",
    setUserName: function (firstName, lastName) {
      this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
};

function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback) {
    callback(firstName, lastName);

    }

getUserInput("My", "Name", clientData.setUserName.bind(clientData));
    console.log (clientData.fullName);
    console.log (window.fullName);
```

Comment: The thing is, `this` is set independently for **every single function call**.  Using `.bind()` is a fine way to address the problem. You could also wrap the call in an anonymous function (which is, more or less, what `.bind()` does for you).

Comment: `.bind()` isn't any sort of magic syntax. It's just a method that creates a new function with the `this` value (and parameters if you include some) bound. It has no impact on the object you're giving it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not actually `bind` `getUserInput`. `Function.prototype.bind()` returns a NEW function with a bound `this` value and passes that as the callback argument.